# SONAR: Members of Spring components should be "@Autowired"

Tags: java, spring, sonarqube, autowired

The SonarJava analyzer introduced in latest release (4.8.0.9441) among others rule [s3749](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/spring/SpringComponentWithNonAutowiredMembersCheck.java) (*Members of Spring components should be "@Autowired"*). It turns out, that SONAR rules out completely other autowiring modes than field injection, i. e. constructor/setter @Autowired doesn't prevent this rule from failing. Is there any rationale behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a wrong rule.

The method should also check @Component

```
private static boolean isSpringComponent(SymbolMetadata clazzMeta) {
    return clazzMeta.isAnnotatedWith("org.springframework.stereotype.Controller")
      || clazzMeta.isAnnotatedWith("org.springframework.stereotype.Service")
      || clazzMeta.isAnnotatedWith("org.springframework.stereotype.Repository");
}
```

Also there might be cases with fields annotated with `@Value("${some.property}"` etc.

Comment: Version 4.9 will address this to some degree. Discussion and community PR are still open. Join in? https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sonarqube/T-f83S9mvQU/discussion